# Por que meu javascript não funciona?

Tags: javascript

Por que ele não funciona ?
estou a alguns minutos tentando entender e segue o código:

```
//funçao de document write
var mostra = function (frase){
    document.write(frase)
};


// pegar elemento
var pegaNome = function (){
    document.getElementById("nome").value="";
};


var escreveDados = function(){
    mostra(pegaNome)
};

function meubotao(){
    (escreveDados)
};
```

Comment: Depende. Como você esta "executando"/chamando esse código esse código? Está importando esse código JS em um arquivo HTML ou esta dentro do próprio HTML.

Comment: está dentro do codigo HTML, eu estou começando agora a estudar javascript

Comment: Qual resultado você está esperando obter ao executar esse código? Poderia [edit] a pergunta com essa informação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu código tem alguns erros, vou comentar e espero que te ajude.

```
//funçao de document write
var mostra = function (frase){
    document.write(frase)
};
```

Este pedaço não tem problemas. Chamando `mostra(algo)` ele vai imprimir esse `algo`.

```
// pegar elemento
var pegaNome = function (){
    document.getElementById("nome").value="";
};
```

Aqui tens um erro estás a apagar o nome do elemento `#nome`, acho que o que queres é ler esse valor, e não apagá-lo. Se queres que esta função retorne esse `nome` deves usar assim: `return document.getElementById("nome").value;`, e quando a função fôr chamada retorna o valor desse elemento.

```
var escreveDados = function(){
    mostra(pegaNome)
};
```

Aqui tens um problema. Tens de invocar a função `pegaNome` com parenteses senão ela não vai correr... podes usar `mostra(pegaNome());`.

```
function meubotao(){
    (escreveDados)
};
```

Aqui tens um problema, parecido com o anterior. Para invocar uma função tens de usar `()`. Nese caso é meio desnecessária a função `meubotao` pois só chama a outra. Eu removeria... mas se queres usar, então em vêz de `(escreveDados)` deves usar `escreveDados();`

Answer (score 1):

`pegaNome()` não retorna uma string que você espera imprimir em `mostra()`.

Faça com que `pegaNome()` retorne uma string qualquer para depuração antes de tentar buscar um valor de elemento.

Outra coisa que está errado no seu código é que ao passar o lambda `pegaNome` para `mostra()`, ele precisa ser acionado usando `()` em um momento, seja na chamada ou internamente em `mostra` como inseri no exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo:

```
var mostra = function (frase) {
    document.write(frase)
};

var pegaNome = function () {
    //document.getElementById("nome").value;

    return 'Foo';
};

var escreveDados = function() {
    mostra(pegaNome())
};

escreveDados();
```

Comment: poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: inseri o exemplo